# ggplot2, qplot, warnings and error about stat_count()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just encountered an error while using ggplot2 and the qplot function (please see below for the warnings and error), and i have no idea about how to make changes so that it will work. I had a look on the past posts related to this problem, but still cannot correct the code.

Could anyone kindly give me some advice?

---

```
> library(ggplot2)
```

> `Warning message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.5`

```
> dodge <- position_dodge(width = .9)

> plot <- qplot(happening, target.looking_M, data=d.c2.subjects, stat="identity",
+   geom="bar", position=dodge,
+   ylab="Proportion of looks", xlab="happening",
+   fill=happening, colour=happening,
+   main="Proportion target looking by condition and testing phase for each single subject")
```

Warning messages:

> ```
> 1: `stat` is deprecated 
>
> 2: `position` is deprecated
> ```

```
> plot <- plot + facet_grid(type ~ subjectname)

> plot
```

> ```
> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
> ```

Comment: Please take the time to learn & type (use IDE snippet expansions if necessary) full ggplot2 `geom_`'s. (a) you'll ultimately make better charts (b) you'll make better use of your IDE (c) I spent some measurable time removing qplot examples from ggplot2. Given some of the other messages you're seeing, you should try to keep your R environment (base binary R install and packages) in a bit more parity.

Answer (score 2):

As the warnings tell, use of `stat` in that way is deprecated in `qplot`. As general advice, I'd steer away from leaning on `qplot` and learn how to use the full `ggplot` syntax, since that gives you much more power.

To make this work though, you can use `geom = "col"` instead. `geom_col` is a new `geom` which behaves like `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.